# How to Insert korean text in ms-sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I tried to insert korean text into my ms sql server table, but it seems not working properly because all characters are broken like "????" as following:

The type of column is **nvarchar**, and I query as follow to put the data: insert into mytable values('텍스트'). And the collation is **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS**, but I wonder if the collation is the problem.

Please help me to find solution

Comment: Sorry, I found myself the solution. The solution is to put 'N' before the values like that: insert into mytable values(N'테스트'). This solution worked fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

While working with nvarchar datatype always use `N'...'`

```
insert into mytable values(N'텍스트');
```

This sqlfiddle example shows the difference if you don't use `N'...'`.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fab9a/1

Comment: Thank you so much! I just found also the same solution like you :)